# How to return a list that is made up of extracted elements from another list in python?

Tags: python, list, append

I am building a function to extract all negatives from a list called xs and I need it to add those extracted numbers into another list called new_home. I have come up with a code that I believe should work, however; it is only showing an empty list.

Example input/output:

> xs=[1,2,3,4,0,-1,-2,-3,-4] ---> new_home=[1,2,3,4,0]

Here is my code that returns an empty list:

```
def extract_negatives(xs):
    new_home=[]
    for num in range(len(xs)):
        if num <0:
            new_home= new_home+ xs.pop(num)
            return
    return new_home
```

Comment: You have an empty return statement in the body of your or statement

Comment: Also, your algorithm runs in quadratic time because of the way you are using `.pop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def extract_negatives(xs):
    new_home=[]
    for num in range(len(xs)):
        if xs[num] < 0:
            new_home.append(xs[num])
    return new_home
```

for your code

But the Chuancong Gao solution is better:

```
def extract_negative(xs):
    return [v for v in xs if v >= 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use

```
[v for v in xs if v >= 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

helper function `filter` could also help. Your function actually is

```
    new_home = filter(lambda x: x>=0, xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop of your code, the num variable doesn't really store the value of the list as you expect. The loop just iterates for `len(xs)` times and passes the current iteration number to `num` variable.

To access the list elements using loop, you should construct loop in a different fashion like this:

```
for element in list_name:
    print element #prints all element.
```

To achieve your goal, you should do something like this:

```
another_list=[]
for element in list_name:
    if(element<0):    #only works for elements less than zero
        another_list.append(element) #appends all negative element to another_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately (or unfortunately, depending on how you look at it) you *aren't examining the numbers in the list (`xs[num]`), you are examining the indexes (`num`)*. This in turn is because as a Python beginner you probably nobody haven't yet learned that there are typically easier ways to iterate over lists in Python.

This is a good (or bad, depending on how you look at it) thing, because had your code taken that branch you would have seen an exception occurring when you attempted to add a number to a list - though I agree the way you attempt it seems natural in English. Lists have an `append` method to put new elements o the end, and `+` is reserved for adding two lists together.

Fortunately ignorance is curable. I've recast your code a bit to show you how you might have written it:

```
def extract_negatives(xs):
    out_list = []
    for elmt in xs:
        if elmt < 0:
            out_list.append(elmt)
    return out_list
```

As @ChuangongGoa suggests with his rather terse but correct answer, a list comprehension such as he uses is a much better way to perform simple operations of this type.

Comment: I haven't learned that far ahead. I'm very new to this and my attempt reflects that.

Comment: I figured, which is why I included lots of explanation. I hope you at least know where you went wrong now. One of the most difficult things about learning to program is getting used to how often you are wrong. But when you finally get it right there's a big payoff!